# PHP Typecasting Error Changing Value

Tags: php, casting

I am trying to store a phone number and I have reached some problems due to type casting? Anyone have any suggestions as to what is happening here?

```
var_dump((int)"6467838439"); // displays 'int 2147483647'
```

Comment: you reached the maximum range of integer in 32-bit system it is `1 to 2147483647` and you have `6467838439`. So when you try to convert it in integer type it is converted to the maximum range of int which is 2147483647. You can only store it as string

Comment: @Shakti Singh: how about float?

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, you can convert to `float` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer is 32 bits and has a finite size of approximatly 2 billion so your phone number is being truncated. You should store it as a string.

Answer (score 4):

Phone numbers should be stored as text. They generally can't be stored as integers due to integer overflow.